# Distributions with simple truncated expectations

Tags: distributions, truncation

For a project I'm looking for continuous distributions which have a somewhat simple  closed form for upper-truncation expectation ($E[x|x>c]$).

Here are two examples I've found so far:

- Exponential distribution $\left(F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}\right)$: $\ c+1/\lambda$
- Uniform distribution on $(a,b)$: $\ \frac{c+b}{2}$

Comment: Big list question... May be too broad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming positive $c$:

The logistic distribution with mean 0, scale parameter $s$ has truncated expectation
$$-ck + s(1+k)\log(1+k),\text{ where }k=e^{c/s}$$

The Laplace distribution with mean 0, scale parameter $b$ has truncated expectation $$(b+c)(1+e^{-c/b})/2$$

Answer (score 8):

The class of distributions with this property is large (and not even completely defined - does an answer in terms of the gamma function, error function etc. count as closed form?). But note that

$$E(X|X > c) = \frac{\int_c^\infty x f(x) dx}{\int_c^\infty f(x) dx} $$

Therefore a closed form for $E(X|X>c)$ will exist so long as both integrals can be found in closed form.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I was looking for simplest examples since the expectation fits into a differential equation and that is ultimately what I hope to have a closed form solution of.